# Why does wp_remote_post returns an empty body response on certain endpoints?

Tags: plugin-development, api, json, http

Im gonna make this brief;

Im using **wp_remote_post** to do a POST request to an external API. My local development environment looks something like "http://website.test". As of now I am requesting to a QA version of this API so the protocol of the endpoints is HTTP. The problem is that the $response object always returns an empty body. If I copy the exact request JSON that im sending over, and the exact HTTP URL of the API, and use it on Postman, I get a normal body response with no issues. So why is the **wp_remote_post** giving me an empty body?

This is how im doing the request:

```
    $response = wp_remote_post( $url_motor . '/' . $this->venta_ep , array(
                    'headers'     => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json' , 'Accept'     => 'application/json'),
                    'body'        => wp_json_encode($params),
                    'method'      => 'POST',
                    'data_format' => 'body',
                )
            );
```

I'm assuming it could have something to do with the fact that its not over HTTPS (neither my local environment, nor the API, but as I said, it works as intended on Postman). I already tried the "blocking" and the "sslverify" options.

Another theory that I have is that it might have something to do with the request body that I am sending over. This is because I am using other endpoints of the same API over HTTP, and some of them DO send a non-empty body back. The pattern that I noticed is that the endpoints that do return a body are the endpoints on which I send an array like this:

```
$arg = wp_json_encode([
    "single_item_json" => [ "1" , "2" , "3"]   
])
```

A simple array with one index that contains an array seems to work. But when I send something like this:

```
$arg = wp_json_encode([
    "multiple_item_json" => [ "1" , "2" , "3"],   
    "multiple_item_json" => [ "1" , "2" , "3"],   
])
```

This one seems to get back an empty body.

I know that my two theories are extremely different, but at this point any kind of insight would be of great help. As I said, what throws me off is that the same request body that gets an empty response body with **wp_remote_post**, when used on Postman, it does get a non-empty , valid response body, so it couldnt possibly be the API, right?

Anyways, thank you for your time and I hope I made my issue clear.

Comment: How are you retrieving the body from `$response`? Are you using [`wp_remote_retrieve_body()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_retrieve_body/)?

Comment: Yes, I am also debugging so I am seeing the actual $response coming back with an empty body in real time

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's possible the remote end is returning an empty response, maybe because it errors out, the response code is important to check ( a 500 code indicates an error ), this is highly unlikely to be a problem with the client side making the request. It could also be a bad request response or a forbidden, if you're only checking the response content/body without checking the response code it's impossible to tell. Also it's unclear it the API being talked to is the WP REST API or a different API.

Comment: @ImgMad I converted your answer to a comment, don't post replies/comments as the solution to someone elses answer. It's also highly unlikely your problem has the same solution as Mauricio's